# Repeat word after pattern

Tags: regex

I want this:

- `[[Actinote alalia`
- `[[Actinote anteas`

to become this:

- `[[Actinote alalia|A. alalia]]`
- `[[Actinote anteas|A. anteas]]`

Comment: What have you tried? Please, show your work.

Comment: @sln post your attempts.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Not really an attempt, more like %80, which is more than the poster did. Find `[[(A)ctinote (alalia)`, replace `$0|$1 $2`

Comment: I realy don't know how to do it. So it is not possible for me to show what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to find and replace:

[`\[\[(\w)\w*\s(\w*)`](https://regex101.com/r/oZsQKN/2/) -> `$0|$1. $2]]`

**OUTPUT**

*IN*

```
[[Actinote alalia
[[Actinote anteas
[[Jorge Eduardo
```

*OUT*

```
[[Actinote alalia|A. alalia]]
[[Actinote anteas|A. anteas]]
[[Jorge Eduardo|J. Eduardo]]
```

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/oZsQKN/2/)